# Build failed with an exception. while generating a signed apk

Tags: android

I am trying to build an application. I can able to build the application properly. Also, I can able to generate the application with debug mode. But when I try to generate the signed apk with release mode, I got the below error.

Please help me what went wrong.

The error is as below

```
:app:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageRelease FAILED


 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> C:\Users\Baba\Project\Application\Artharakshak\Code\Artharakshak\app\release\app-release.apk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
30 actionable tasks: 29 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Below is my progourd file

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in C:\Users\Baba\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-ignorewarnings
```

Build Version is

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the advice in your console's output, and run it with the `--stacktrace` option? `app:packageRelease --stacktrace`. What did it say?

Comment: Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\Baba\Project\Application\Artharakshak\Code\Artharakshak\app\release\app-release.apk
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
 at

Comment: I got an error like above

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution.

Problem Reason:

There is some access issue in windows after upgrading my Android Studio, As a result, an existing project developed on older version could not write the apk in the same place.
Even after cleaning the project will not help.

Solution:

I create a new project in a different location. This helps to build and generate the apk file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you put an incorrect password

you need to add this code inside `gradle.properties`

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=your_password
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=your_password
```